# Smooth increasing of element width while reducing screen width

Tags: css, less, responsive

I have some code in the `style.less` file:

```
.wrapper {
  width: 64%;

  @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    width: 82%;
  }

  @media screen and (max-width: 320px) {
    width: 94%;
  }
}
```

As you see, the width of the `.wrapper` element must be 82% when the screen width is 768px.

Is it possible to write any function which would allow to make smooth increasing of `.wrapper` element width every 64 pixels?

64 pixels were got as follows:

> (1920px - 768px) / 18, where 18 are percents between 64 and 82

Comment: that what you mean:https://jsfiddle.net/gc15nu2h/

Comment: I'm sorry, but element width in this fiddle doesn't increasing, when I'm reducing screen width

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [Codepen demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zeKKqg)

---

You could use a less `loop` to define the width for the 18 breakpoints and you could define a transition over the width to have a smooth resize

```
@iterations: 0;
.wrapper {
  transition: width .5s 0s;

  .wrapper-for (@i) when (@i < 19) {
     @media screen and (max-width: (1920px - @i * 64)) { width: (64% + @i); }
     .wrapper-for(@i + 1);
  }
  .wrapper-for (@iterations);
}
```

---

This compiles into

```
.wrapper {
  transition: width .5s 0s;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1920px) {
  .wrapper {
    width: 64%;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1856px) {
  .wrapper {
    width: 65%;
  }
}

//[14 breakpoints]...

@media screen and (max-width: 832px) {
  .wrapper {
    width: 81%;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .wrapper {
    width: 82%;
  }
}
```

Comment: It helped me, thank you very much! May I fork your CodePen example?

Comment: You're welcome, feel free to use that example as you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

If we consider the fact that your element will be `64%` at `1920px` the `82%` at `768px` so your element need to go from `1228.8px` to `629.76px` we can also see it as `100vw - 691.2px` to `100vw - 138.24px`.

We can also write it like below

```
  100vw - (691.2px - X)
```

Where X should be `0` at `1920px` and `552.96px` at `768px`. we can write it `1920px - 100vw` which will give as our `0` but when at `768px` it will give us `1152px` which is almost twice `552.94px` thus we can write `X` as `(1920px - 100vw)/2,08` then our formula will be

```
  100vw - 691.2px + (1920px - 100vw)/2,08
```

In the example below, when the screen size is at `768px` the red should be almost equal to the blue and when at 1920px it should be equal to the green:

```css
.box {
 width:calc(100vw - 691.2px + (1920px - 100vw)/2.08);
 height:50px;
 background:red;
}
.one,
.two {
  height:50px;
}
.one {
  width:64%;
  background:green;
}
.two {
  width:82%;
  background:blue;
}


body {
 margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
</div>

<div class="one">
</div>

<div class="two">
</div>
```

The above logic will create a linear transtion between `1920px` and `768px` from `64%` to `82%`. You may notice that at `320px` you will not have `94%` because that point doesn't belong to the linear function we defined. At `320px` we will have `100vw + 78.03px` thus it's `124%`.

You may use another formula if you want another linear transtion from `768px` to `320px` to have `82%` and `94%`

```
  100vw - 138.24px + (768px - 100vw)/3.76
```

```css
.box {
 width:calc(100vw - 691.2px + (1920px - 100vw)/2.08);
 height:50px;
 background:red;
}
.one,
.two,
.three{
  height:50px;
}
.one {
  width:64%;
  background:green;
}
.two {
  width:82%;
  background:blue;
}

.three {
  width:94%;
  background:purple;
}



@media all and (max-width:768px) {
 .box {
   width:calc(100vw - 138.24px + (768px - 100vw)/3.76);
 }

}

body {
 margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
</div>

<div class="one">
</div>

<div class="two">
</div>

<div class="three">
</div>
```

With the above code we will now have `94%` at `320px` keeping the other percentage.