# Calculating fluid CSS element sizes using CSS using calc(px + vw)

Tags: css, math, css-calc

Using this method here: https://css-tricks.com/fun-viewport-units/

I want to calculate how to achieve a specific amount of change between view port sizes **1920px and 375px**

**Example:** I want my element of 150px to reduce in size by 40px between 1920px and 375px

### The problem:

I'm not sure what equation I should be using to best define my input values.

I tried taking the desired size of 150px at 1920px adding 40px divided 19.2 (2.083vw) minus 40px:

```
width: calc(150px + (2.083vw - 40px))
```

It's very close, but not quite there, just shy of **150px at 1920px**, but **117px at 375px**.

I also tried using 40px divide by the difference between viewport sizes 15.45:

```
width: calc(150px + (2.588vw - 40px))
```

But that was much further away **160px at 1920px** and **119px at 375px**:

### Part solution:

If I fiddle the numbers as seen with the element **boxfix** it's right (or close eneough not to care about the half px each way)

```
width: calc(150px + (2.56vw - 49.5px))
```

As I don't want to have to fiddle the numbers each time I'm hoping there's a way to calculate what the value of each should be with more accuracy, or if there's a better sum I could be using to achieve the same thing.

### JS Fiddle:

Here's a JSFiddle in case it's useful: https://jsfiddle.net/8qdptyj3/1/

```css
body {
  font-size: 18px;
}

.box {
  width: calc(150px + (2.083vw - 40px))
}

.boxfix {
  width: calc(150px + (2.56vw - 49.5px))
}
```

```html
<div class="box" style="background:red;color:white;margin:10px;">
  Hello World
</div>
<div class="boxfix" style="background:red;color:white;margin:10px;">
  Hello World
</div>
```

Comment: It sounds like you need media queries rather than CSS calc.

Comment: what you want is a discrete change not a linear change so you don't need to use a function for it

Comment: @AHaworth using media queries kind of defeats the point of what I'm trying to achieve

Comment: @TemaniAfif Can you explain what you mean? I'm trying to get a linear change in size so I don't have to use media queries if that's what you're getting at? Or at least minimize the use of them.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more what you want? I read it that if the viewport is between 375px and 1920px then you want the element to take on width 150px - 40px.

Comment: @AHaworth I want the size of the element to have a gradual change between the two points media queries will jump the size in steps, which is not what I want.

Comment: explain that *gradual* change, that part is not clear in your question

Comment: What is the gradual change? Is it that you take nothing off for viewport of 1920px and then go up to taking 40px off for viewport of 375px. And is that linear?

Comment: this is the calc you would need to do `calc(150px - ((1920px - 100vw) * (40px / 1545px)))` calc can't do multiplication or division though so you can't do it with css

Comment: How can I make it more clear in the question? I'm not sure where the confusion is, I want to be able to reduce the size of an element at a linear rate from Size A at 1920px to Size B at 375px and I need to know what equation should be used to calculate the reduction rate using calc.

Comment: is this kind of logic what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54418027/8620333 ?

Comment: @Pete thank you, calc can do multiplication and division, I do it all the time. But it has issues with it when trying to do it with variable unit values like vw and vh etc.

Comment: You might want to check this Codepen [Responsive and fluid typography, the easy way](https://codepen.io/renevanderlende/full/YzEaKvO) I created a few weeks back. Section 'y=mx+b Math in a Nutshell' shows the math you can use for any size related CSS property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to solve the equation `Y = A*X + B` where in your case `Y` is the width and `X` is `100vw` So `width: calc(A*100vw + B)`

When `100vw = 1920px` you need `width: 150px` so we have

```
150px = A*1920px + B
```

When `100vw = 375px` you need `width: 110px` so we have

```
110px = A*375px + B
```

We do some math and we get `A = 0.026` and `B = 100.3`

Your code is `width: calc(0.026*100vw + 100.3px)` Also `width: calc(2.6vw + 100.3px)`

---

You can also write it as

```
--a: ((150 - 110)/(1920 - 375));
--b: 150px - 1920px*var(--a);  /* OR 110px - 375px*var(--a) */
width: calc(var(--a)*100vw + var(--b));
```

```css
body {
  font-size: 18px;
}

.box {
  width: calc(2.6vw + 100.3px);
  height: 100px;
}

.box-alt {
  --a: ((150 - 110)/(1920 - 375));
  --b: 150px - 1920px*var(--a);
  width: calc(var(--a)*100vw + var(--b));
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box" style="background:red;color:white;margin:10px;">

</div>

<div class="box-alt" style="background:red;color:white;margin:10px;">

</div>
```

Comment: It's very close, seems to be off by half a px at each view port size, I just made an adjustment to mine by figuring out if you take 40px / 15.45 and then subtract the value of the extra width at 375px 9.15px added to the desired width 110px `width: calc(150px + (2.5889vw - 49.15px))` the size comes out bang on. Obvious that's a tadious way to go about it for every size but it works perfectly, any ideas how to get to that sum, without having to work it out by hand each time? Thank you for the answer though it's definately got me a lot closer

Comment: @GibsonFX `width: calc(150px + (2.5889vw - 49.15px))` is equal to `width: calc(100.85px + 2.5889vw)` ... compare it with my result and you will see it's the same. Everything else is all about rounding and instead of using 2.5889 I simply used 2.6 because in CSS it doesn't make a visual difference ... I already gave the formula in case you want to get the correct "math" values

Comment: I cut and paste your code box-alt into my JSfiddle and it seems to be coming out slightly different each way. I noticed you've not put a calc function round the --b sum is that the reason?

Comment: @GibsonFX as I said, it's all about rounding. CSS will not do precise math .. both formula may look the same but they are not in practical. Having a difference of 1px is expected

Comment: Thank you, just out of curiosity, why does the --b variable work without using calc function?

Comment: @GibsonFX even for --a the calc is not needed .. we don't do any calculation inside variable, we only store "something' that will later get used. It's a kind of substitution